# Is there a way to set a path for an image with unkown extention?

Tags: javascript, path

So I am making a website using javascript and I was wondering if theres a way to set a path for the src of an image tag without knowing what extention will be. The path is known, the image filename aswell but the extention of the image is not. How could I set the src, considering that any valid extention of the image would be fine?

Comment: Sure, you can manage that on the server-side

Comment: You shouldn't think of an HTTP server as file server.  The source attribute is an identifier for a ressource, a URI (Universal Ressource Identifier).  What that ressource is, is decided by the http server. You could have `src="http://localhost:8080/a_path"` and get an image or `src="http://localhost:8080/image.jpg"` and get a Word document or a data stream.